# Forge Viewer: Search or Model Browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do I enable search on a 2D view in the forge viewer. Looks like the model browser is only available on 3D views. Is there a way to enable it on 2D views as well

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly adding loading the ModelStructure extension does the trick.

```
        viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure')
```